# system.web.ui.datavisualization.Charting dll error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, microsoft-chart-controls

Morning all,

I stumbled on this perticular nasty error where i use an asp.net chart control (v4.0)
when i drag a chart control on my page using VS2010, i see the assemblies are being made. But then again i immediatelly get some errors that say i can't use the chart control.

My web.config file contains the following code for the chart control

```
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"/>
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

My aspx.vb file contains the following import

```
Imports System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
```

However, here i already get the following error:
Namespace or type specified in the imports 'system.web.UI.dataVisualization.Charting' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found ...

in my aspx file the first line of code has error curves

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Datalogging.aspx.vb" Inherits="Datalogging" %>
```

Whereas the error = Type 'system.web.ui.Datavisualization.Charting.chart' is not defined.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Robin

EDIT:

Seemed i had some troubles with the framework versions

I rebuilded the app in v3.5 and after that i rebuilded the app again in v4.0

Conclusion, the app works again.

Thanks for those who were searching for a solution